# Where is links__system_main_menu defined?

Tags: 7, theming

I searched for `links__system_main_menu`, but just find usages of this theme. Where is it defined?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Drupal 7 core doesn't actually define this function.

`links__system_main_menu` is a theme hook pattern of the form `[base hook]__[context]`. When links are themed with `theme('links__system_main_menu', $vars)`, `theme()` will search for and use `theme_links__system_main_menu()` if it has been defined. If not, it will use `theme_links()`.

See [theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme/7) for the official documentation of this behavior. Chapter 3 of [Drupal 7 Module Development](https://www.packtpub.com/drupal-7-module-development/book) does an excellent job of explaining this and provides several examples.

BTW, the same principle applies to template files. If, for example, we call `theme('node__article__1', $vars)`, `theme()` will search for a `node--article--1.tpl.php` file, and then for `node--article.tpl.php`, finally falling back to `node.tpl.php` if neither of them are defined.

Answer (score 11):

`theme_links__system_main_menu()` is not currently defined from Drupal, but Drupal will use `MYTHEME_links__system_main_menu()`, if you define it in your theme.

```
function MYTHEME_links__system_main_menu($variables) {
  $html = "<div>\n";
  $html .= "  <ul>\n"; 

  foreach ($variables['links'] as $link) {
    $html .= "<li>".l($link['title'], $link['path'], $link)."</li>";
  }

  $html .= "  </ul>\n";
  $html .= "</div>\n";

  return $html;
}
```

You can find some more info on http://drupal.org/node/1033442#comment-5076932.