# purpose of links__system_secondary_menu

Tags: navigation

Could someone please explain to me the purpose of the following piece of code?

```
<?php print theme('links__system_secondary_menu', array(
  'links' => $secondary_menu,
  'attributes' => array(
    'id' => 'secondary-menu',
    'class' => array('links', 'inline', 'clearfix'),
  ),
  'heading' => array(
    'text' => $secondary_menu_heading,
    'level' => 'h2',
    'class' => array('element-invisible'),
  ),
)); ?>
```

I have researched for quite some time and could not find an answer to it. It would seem this is in all Drupal7 themes and if removed, the "My account" and "Log out" links disappear.

Comment: See http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15652/where-is-links-system-main-menu-defined for a very good explanation. It concentrates on `links__system_main_menu` but the idea is exactly the same.