# bartik_links__system_main_menu() doesn't work

Tags: theming

When I implement `bartik_links__system_main_menu($variables)` in my `template.php` file, there is nothing different in the main menu than the previous one. I've changed some of the markup in this function; I checked it in the theme developer, and the function that is responsible for the main menu is still `theme_links()` rather than `bartik_links__system_main_menu($variables)`.

Why?

Comment: I'm assuming that you are actually using the Bartik theme, correct?

Comment: yes,i am using bartik

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that:

1. `theme('links__system_main_menu', ...` is actually used to output the menu.
2. There are no issues with your code.
3. Caches have been cleared after adding the function (admin/config/development/performance).

To better understand what `system_main_menu` is all about check keithm's answer [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15652/where-is-links-system-main-menu-defined). The main part of the explanation is this:

> `links__system_main_menu` is a theme hook pattern of the form `[base
>   hook]__[context]`. When links are themed with
>   `theme('links__system_main_menu', $vars)`, `theme()` will search for
>   and use `theme_links__system_main_menu()` if it has been defined. If
>   not, it will use `theme_links()`.

Official documentation about it can be found [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme/7).