# Where are the main menu links created?

Tags: 7, routes

I've been doing some w3 validation but I find that my menu's are missing a `<ul>` for the `<li>`'s. I have read [Where is links__system_main_menu defined?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15652/where-is-links-system-main-menu-defined) but this doesn't really answer my question. I understand that

> links__system_main_menu is a theme hook pattern of the form [base
>   hook]__[context]. When links are themed with
>   theme('links__system_main_menu', $vars), theme() will search for and
>   use theme_links__system_main_menu() if it has been defined. If not, it
>   will use theme_links().

The theme i'm using doesn't do much as far as modify the menu system at first glance. In the theme.php file, it contains:

```
$variables['main_menu_themed'] = theme(
    'links__system_main_menu',
    array(
      'links' => $variables['main_menu'],
      'attributes' => array(
        'id' => '',
        'class' => array('links', 'clearfix'),
      ),
      'heading' => array(
        'text' => t('Main menu'),
        'level' => 'h2',
        'class' => array('element-invisible'),
      ),
    )
  );
```

How can I modify the actual output of the menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override `theme_links__system_main_menu()` by declaring a function in your theme's template.php file:

```
function MYTHEME_links__system_main_menu($vars) {
  $links = $vars['links'];

  $items = array();
  foreach ($links as $link) {
    $items[] = l($link['title'], $link['href']);
  }

  return theme('item_list', array('items' => $items));
}
```

The above is a very basic example, you'll probably want to take a look at the original code for [`theme_links()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_links/7) to make that a bit more bulletproof.