# Can't override links__system_main_menu in Drupal

Tags: navigation, theming

Im working on my custom theme (modified stark theme) and there is a main menu in `page.tpl.php` generated by:

```
<?php print theme('links__system_main_menu', array('links' => $main_menu, 'attributes' => array('id' => 'main-menu', 'class' => array('links', 'inline', 'gold')))); ?>
```

I want to define my own html for main menu so I created a `template.php` file with this function:

```
function budo_links__system_main_menu($variables) {
  $html = "<div style='background-color:red;'>\n";
  $html .= "  <ul>\n";  
  foreach ($variables['links'] as $link) {
    $html .= "<li>".l($link['title'], $link['path'], $link)."</li>";
  }
  $html .= "  </ul>\n";
  $html .= "</div>\n";
  return $html;
}
```

where `budo` is a name of my theme. But menu is still generated old way and not by this new function. It should work according to [this explanation](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15652/where-is-links-system-main-menu-defined), but it doesn't even if I flush cache. Did I forget something?

Comment: I run your code and working fine. There can be some other kind of silly mistake. :)

Comment: yes, I forgot to change name of theme.info

Comment: Yeah!! That happens to me sometimes too. :)